# Print two List of model type by time

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 List of model type that is initialized in controller and inserted value in them and then assign these list object to Viewdata so that I can iterate through this list using forach.But problem is that Model of these 2 list have Property Time so that I want to print these 2 List orderby their time.
Here is my code.

Model of List1:

```
public class Likes
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPhoto { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Posttext { get; set; }
    public int? PId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Liketime { get; set; }
}
```

Model of List2:

```
public class Comments
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPhoto { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public int? PId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Commenttime { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Home()
{   
    List<Likes> List = new List<Likes>();
    var f = (from n in _db.PostLikes where n.ToWhomId == CurrentUser.User.Id join o in _db.Users on n.UserId equals o.Id join p in _db.Posts on n.PostId equals p.Id   select new { Name = o.UserName, Photo = o.UserPhoto, ID = n.UserId, PID = n.PostId ,p.PostText,n.Time }).ToList().OrderByDescending(n=>n.Time);
    foreach (var item in f)
    {
        Likes mylikes = new Likes()
        {
            PId = item.PID,
            UserName = item.Name,
            UserPhoto = item.Photo,
            Posttext=item.PostText,
            Liketime=item.Time
        };
        List.Add(mylikes);
    }
    ViewData["likes"] = List;
    List<Comments> List2 = new List<Comments>();
    var qw = (from n in _db.PostComments where n.ToWhomId == CurrentUser.User.Id join o in _db.Users on n.UserId equals o.Id join p in _db.Posts on n.PostId equals p.Id select new { Name = o.UserName, Photo = o.UserPhoto, ID = n.UserId, PID = n.PostId, p.PostText, n.Time, Comment = n.Comments }).ToList().OrderByDescending(n => n.ID);
    foreach (var item in qw)
    {
        Comments mycomments = new Comments()
        {
            PId = item.PID,
            UserName = item.Name,
            UserPhoto = item.Photo,
            CommentText = item.PostText,
            Commenttime = item.Time
        };
        List2.Add(mycomments);
    }
    ViewData["comments"] = List2;
    return View(posts);
}
```

View:

```
foreach (var item in (dynamic)ViewData["likes"])
{
    if (item.Posttext == null)
    {
        var trim = item.Posttext.Substring(0, 5) + "...";
        item.Posttext = "";
    }
    else
    {
        var trim = item.Posttext + " ";
        item.Posttext = trim;
    }
    <li>
        <a href="~/Profile/Index">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="~/Images/@item.UserPhoto" width="40" height="40" />
            <p style="color:black"><b>@item.UserName</b> liked your post @item.Posttext </p>
           <img width="16" height="16" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/like-128.png")" />
           <span style="color:black"> @item.Liketime</span>
        </a>
    </li>
}
foreach (var item in (dynamic)ViewData["comments"])
{
    // trim here
    <li>
        <a href="~/Profile/Index">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="~/Images/@item.UserPhoto" width="40" height="40" />
            <p style="color:black"><b>@item.UserName</b> commented on your post </p>
            <img width="16" height="16" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Custom-Icon-Design-Flatastic-1-Comment (1).ico")" />
            <span style="color:black"> @item.Commenttime</span>
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

But I don't want to print `List2` after `List1`. I want to print them by `Time` if `list1` model inserted first it should print if `list2` it should print until end of both list.

Comment: So you want to iterate through both lists simultaneously, printing out the item that comes next chronologically, regardless which list it's in?

Comment: Not trying to be *very* nit picky but this line is quite concerning `List<Likes> List = new List<Likes>();`.. why give a List the name "List"?  How is that beneficial, or easier to maintain down the road?

Comment: You need to create a view model containing a property `string Text` and `DateTime Time` (and any other common properties) then project your queries to collections of that view model, concatenate them, sort by `Time` an return the collection to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display `Likes` and `Comments` in one list, ordered by `Time`, then create a view model so that you can project your queries to that view model, concatenate them to one collection and then sort by `Time`.

Based on the view you have shown, your view model will be

```
public class ResponseVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:...}")] // your format
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming that your displaying these associated with a parent model (say `Post`), then you would also have

```
public class PostVM
{
    .... // properties of Post needed for the view
    public IEnumerable<ResponseVM> Responses { get; set; }
}
```

The GET method will then be

```
var likes = (from n in _db.PostLikes where ....).ToList().Select(x => new ResponseVM()
{
    Name = x.Name,
    Photo = Url.Content(String.Format("~/Images/{0}", x.Photo)),
    Message = String.Format(" liked your post {0}", x.PostText), // see notes below
    Image = Url.Content("~/Images/like-128.png"),
    Time = x.Time
});

var comments = (from n in _db.PostComments where ...).ToList().Select(x => new ResponseVM()
{
    .... // as above except adjust Message and Image properties
});
// Combine and order
var responses = likes.Concat(comments).OrderBy(x => x.Time);
PostVM model = new PostVM()
{
    ....
    Responses = responses
};
return View(model);
```

And the view will be

```
@model PostVM
....
<ul>
    @foreach(var response in Model.Responses)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="~/Profile/Index">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="@response.Photo" width="40" height="40" />
                <p style="color:black"><b>@item.Name</b>@response.Message</p>
                <img width="16" height="16" src="@reponse.Image" />
                <span style="color:black">@Html.DisplayFor(m => response.Time</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Side note: Its not clear what your trying to do with your 'trim' code in your view. In the `if` block you set a variable `var trim = ...` but never use it, and then you set `Posttext` to an empty string which is pointless. In the `else` block you appear to be just adding space to the end which is unnecessary. In any case, that type of code belongs in the controller, not the view.

Answer (score 0):

So You basically wants to run through both arrays simultaneously and pick the object with lower time then the other. So You always need to have current index of each array and that's it.

There are 2 ways to this:

1) Let's imagine that You have **ordered** & prepared 2 lists, one of Comments & one of likes. You will take the earliest comment/like and add it to the list of results:

```
List<Comments> lComments = someList.OrderBy(a => a.Commenttime);
List<Likes> lLikes = someList2.OrderBy(a => a.Liketime);
List<object> lResults = new List<object>();

int iComment = 0, iLike = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < lComments.Count() + lLikes.Count(); i++)
{
    if(lComments.Count() >= iComment) //set Like
    {
        lResults.Add(lLikes[iLike++]);
        continue;
    }

    if(lLikes.Count() >= iLike ) //set Comment
    {
        lResults.Add(lComments[iComment++]);
        continue;
    }

    if(lLikes[iLike].Liketime > lComments[iComment].Commenttime)
        lResults.Add(lComments[iComment++]);
    else
        lResults.Add(lLikes[iLike++]);
}
```

2) The other way around is to make it more "professional" way, You will use [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, where the Likes & Comments can compare among. Implementation of this interface will grant You permission to easily sort these elements. So will just put all objects from Commens and Likes to 1 list/array, and You will sort that:

```
public class Likes : IComparable<T>
{
    //previous implementation...
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is Comments)
            return this.Liketime.CompareTo((obj as Comments).Commenttime);
        if(obj is Likes)
            return this.Liketime.CompareTo((obj as Likes).Liketime);
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

public class Comments: IComparable<T>
{
    //previous implementation...
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is Comments)
            return this.Commenttime.CompareTo((obj as Comments).Commenttime);
        if(obj is Likes)
            return this.Commenttime.CompareTo((obj as Likes).Liketime);
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

// And now You just need to use them to sort:

List<Comments> lComments = someList.OrderBy(a => a.Commenttime);
List<Likes> lLikes = someList2.OrderBy(a => a.Liketime);
List<object> lResults = new List<object>(lComments);
lResults.AddRange(lLikes);
lResults.Sort();
```

Please note that I have ommit all security checks (null reference checks), etc..

Comment: Thankyou very much tatranskymedved but you did not tell me how to print them in view?